# How to customize iRate classes for "Rate this app" ios

Tags: ios, uiview, irate

I don't want to use the uialertview for the popup, that gives the user a chance to rate the app on ios. I want to use a customized popup, but this is not showing up. Besides using the iRate classes from the internet, I also create a xib, that contains the popup, that I want to appear and I changed in .h from :NSObject to :UIViewController. I commented all the code for the uialertview and in the method promptForRating, that will be triggered, I make the uiview from the xib visible, but apparently the uiview is nil.

```
- (void)promptForRating
{
    rateView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Does anybody have a suggestion about making this popup show up?

Comment: If it is nil.. maybe you forgot to instantiate it (or didn't do it properly)?

Comment: But if i create it in the .xib, doesn't it instantiate itself?:) And I used IBOutlet for that UIView, in order to make it visible in the implementation.

Comment: UIView *myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: myView is not nil, but unfortunately it doesn't become visible.

Comment: In your view controllers viewDidLoad:

[self.view addSubView:myView]

Comment: viewDidLoad is not triggered in iRate; if I add it in initwithnibname there appears EXC_BAD_ACCESS. If I add it in the method promptForRating, xcode crashes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get it now.. if you want to display a view, it has to be embedded in a view controller. Or in another view that is already embedded.

What you can do is

- Access the sharedApplication of the UIApplication
- Get all the UIWindows of that UIApplication (in reversed order, because your myView should be on top)
- Select the UIWindow that is the default
- Add your myView as a subview of the UIWindow

At least this is what SVProgressHUD is doing.

Here is some sample code

```
if(!myView.superview){
    NSEnumerator *frontToBackWindows = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]windows]reverseObjectEnumerator];

    for (UIWindow *window in frontToBackWindows)
        if (window.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal) {
            [window addSubview:myView];
            break;
        }
}
```

The first line is to ensure that your view is not visible atm (maybe unnecessary in your context). To dismiss the view, remove it from its superview.

Comment: Man I want to thank you a lot for your effort. :) It works. I couldn't have done it without you! Thanks again.